# Update table based on another table with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to update all columns where the `post_type = product` and the `post_status = publish`. Furthermore I need to make a join because I want to update only those posts, where also the `Count(...)` is 0.

I want to count the meta `meta_key LIKE "%product_shops_%_price%"`.

Here are two examples of the tables:

wp441_posts:

```
| ID | post_status | post_type |
--------------------------------
|  1 |   publish   |  product  |
|  2 |    darf     |  product  |
|  3 |    darf     |  product  |
|  4 |   publish   |    page   |
|  5 |   publish   |    page   |
|  6 |   publish   |    page   |
--------------------------------
```

wp441_postmeta:

```
| meta_id | post_id |        meta_key         | met_value |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  1      |    1    |  product_shops_0_price  |    45.00  
|  2      |    1    |  product_shops_1_price  |    25.00  |
|  3      |    1    |  product_shops_2_price  |    45.00  |
|  4      |    2    |       thumbnail_url     | https://..|
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

For example. In the two tables I only want to set the `post_status` of the `ID` 1 to `draft` because this is the only post where my conditions are matching. I have more then 0 `product_shops_%_price` prices in the wp441_postmeta table, I have a post which is on `publish` at the moment and it is a `product``.

I already tinkered a statement but this one is without join at the moment:

```
SELECT COUNT(meta_key) FROM `wp441_postmeta` WHERE meta_key LIKE "%product_shops_%_price%" GROUP BY (post_id)
```

Now I need to insert the join in this statement. But I have no idea how... Can somebody help me please?

Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your explained case to update `wp441_posts.post_status` to value `draft` where:

- `post_type = 'product AND post_status = 'public'`
- and matching `post_id` with `wp441_postmeta.post_id` having more than 1 row where `meta_key LIKE '%product_shops_%_price%'`

the statement would look like this:

```
UPDATE wp441_posts p
JOIN (
  SELECT pm.post_id
  FROM wp441_postmeta
  WHERE meta_key LIKE '%product_shops_%_price%'
  GROUP BY pm.post_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
  ) pm
  ON p.id = pm.post_id
SET post_status = 'draft'
WHERE pm.post_type = 'product' AND pm.post_status = 'publish'
```

I think your `LIKE` should compare with `product_shops_%_price` without additional `%` sign at the beggining and end of the string, but that's specific to how WordPress puts values in there. Consider it though.